# How can I change the CSS of a specific word?

Tags: jquery, html, css, class

I've been searching for this answer for a while but could not find any specific information on this.

To put it down in words:
I want to change the color of a specific words in a class.

Example:
if the class contains the word Online it would make it a green color.
if the class contains the word Offline it would make it red.

now for the code:

```
<section class="even">
                <h5>Voltz 2.0.4</h5>
                <span class="tag version"><span>1.5.2</span></span>
                <div class="serverinfo">
                    <p>Status: <span class="status"></span></p>
                    <p>Players: <span class="voltz-onlineplayers"></span>/<span class="voltz-maxonlineplayers"></span></p>
                    <p>IP: voltz.arcadia.eu</p>
                </div>
                <a class="button" href="vote.html#voltz">Vote</a>
                <a class="button" href="modpacks.html#voltz">Modpack Info</a>
            </section>
```

the class voltz-online will either fill in the word online or offline regarding on the response of the server (already been done).

but i want to check if the class status contains the word online or offline.
I'm not entirely sure what I should use to get that effect.

I'm pretty sure I have to use this function but that's as far as I got.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        //code to change color here.
    });
```

I'd be great if anyone could explain this with an example code.
And feel free to ask questions if you're missing information

**Edit:**
to give a visual example of what I mean to make things a bit more simple.
[image: http://prntscr.com/apgb5p]

where i want the highlighted text to become green when it says Online and red when it says Offline.

Comment: Why not give the elements you want to change more than one class?  Instead of `voltz-online` use `voltz online`.  Then you just need one class for online and one for offline.

Comment: Well since my knowlege about javascript is limited I have to use diffrent classes for every server i'm running to retrieve the information from the right IP. So thats why i added a second class so i only have to do it once instead of adding it to every diffrent class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this easily with CSS.

```
[class*=online] {
  color: green;
}
[class*=offline] {
  color: red;
}
```

This CSS selector is looking for any element with an attribute named `class` and the `*=` is telling the browser to look if the following string exists anywhere within that attribute's value.

So any classes with name `something-online` or `offline-something` or any combination will be matched by this selector.

You can use this same selector with jquery and set the css styles, but using script for this is unnecessary.

**Edit:**

Thanks to UndoingTech for providing a link to the attribute selectors reference. I'm including it in the answer to make it easier to find http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp

Attribute selectors are extremely powerful and often overlooked. Since jQuery uses CSS selectors, all attribute selectors work in script as well.

**Edit:**

Based on clarification on the original question, here is the proper solution for changing the `color` style of an element with a particular class based on the text inside of that element.

```
$(function() {
  $(".status").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase();
    if (text === "offline") {
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    } else if (text === "online") {
      $(this).css("color", "green");
    }
  });
});
```

This code finds all elements with the `.status` class, then `.each()` loops through each element and calls the inline function once for each element. This function trims and converts all text to lowercase, and then compares the value of that text with either "offline" or "online" and then sets the css color of the element accordingly.

Comment: Very nice.  For those who are unfamiliar with CSS attribute selectors: [W3Schools CSS Attribute Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).  They can be *very* helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm not entirely sure how to get this to work.
I've been unable to change the style of the word inside the span named status

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon There is no word inside the `<span class="status">`.  There aren't any words in the other `<span>`s either.  Are you saying that you want to apply styles based on the text inside the `<span class="status">`?

Comment: @UndoingTech Yes. I've added a picture to explain things better. The text inside the span is generated trough an API.

Comment: @DarkEyeDragon i've updated my answer to reflect this new information

Comment: Nice explanation.  I can't +1 anymore :(  Also, is `$(function(){});` equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){});`?  I've seen it many times but I've never been sure if they are exactly the same.

Comment: @UndoingTech yes, `$(function(){});` is just a shorthand

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting the picture.  It really cleared things up.

Here is a jQuery solution.  I wasn't sure if you had more than one status per page, so I made it work just in case you had more than one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var status = $(".status");
      status.each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).text() == "Online") {
            $(this).css("color", "green");
          } else {
            if ($(this).text() == "Offline") {
              $(this).css("color", "red");
            } // end if
          } // enf else
        }); // end each
      }); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="even">
  <h5>Voltz 2.0.4</h5>
  <span class="tag version"><span>1.5.2</span></span>
  <div class="serverinfo">
    <p>Status: <span class="status">Offline</span>
    </p>
    <p>Players: <span class="voltz-onlineplayers"></span>/<span class="voltz-maxonlineplayers"></span>
    </p>
    <p>IP: voltz.arcadia.eu</p>
  </div>
  <a class="button" href="vote.html#voltz">Vote</a>
  <a class="button" href="modpacks.html#voltz">Modpack Info</a>
</section>
```

I could not have made this answer without this helpful documentation on [jQuery selecor.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. And yes i have about 5 of those on a page. So thanks for already including that.

Comment: Welp. Seems like its not working as intended. It works fine when i fill in the words myself in the span. But it doesnt seem to detect that the API has put a string there. I tried using the `window.onload` but that didn't work either unless i put the word in the between the spans myself. I'll upload a working code to jsfiddle or code snippet and put it as an edit in the original question.

Comment: Is the API also JavaScript?  If so, you can make this into a function and call it at the end of your API call.  Or you could try putting the script at the bottom of the body, though I'm not sure that will make a difference.

Comment: The API is also JavaScript. I tried implementing it in the function too but it makes not diffrence. Here's a recreation of it: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mehmkhrc/3/) I'm really not comfortable with javascript. So it might just be a stupid mistake i made or an easy fix for you.

Comment: I've made some edits to the fiddle.  I took out the jQuery answer and added styling to your code.  Is [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mehmkhrc/4/) good?

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot for the help. I really appreciate you taking the time for this. +1

Answer (score 0):

@Joel's answer is much better, but since you asked for a solution in jQuery, this would help.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     var status = $('.status');
     if(status.hasClass('voltz-online')) {
          status.css('color', 'green');
     } else if (status.hasClass('voltz-offline')) {
          status.css('color', 'red');
      } 
});
```

Comment: You can use [jQuery's selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_attribute_equal_value.asp) to do the same thing Joel did with CSS.  `$.("[class*=online]").css('color', 'green');`  I'm not sure if that works, but it should be something like that.  Kudos for using jQuery.

Comment: @UndoingTech absolutely! My only argument is that OP said he doesnt know much about jQuery, so it's best to start with something simple.